# str.contains to create new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am exploring the titanic data set and want to create a column with similar names. For example, any name that contains "Charles" will show as "ch",as I want to do some group by using those later on.
I created a function using the following code:

```
def cont(Name):
    for a in Name:
        if a.str.contains('Charles'):
            return('Ch')
```

and then applied using this:

```
titanic['namest']=titanic['Name'].apply(cont,axis=1)
```

Error: `'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

[notebook_link](https://github.com/mezud/python-notes/blob/master/kaggle-titanic.ipynb)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than use a loop or `apply` you can use the vectorised `str.contains` to return a boolean mask and set all rows where the condition is met to your desired value:

```
titanic.loc[titanic['Name'].str.contains('Charles'), 'namest'] = 'Ch'
```

Answer (score 4):

`apply` will call the `cont` function and pass it a value from the `Name` column, a value by value. That means that the `Name` variable inside the `cont` function is already a string.

Also note that every function that is being used by `apply` must return something, so in case the name doesn't contain 'Charles' the name itself is returned.

Also 2, `Series` `apply` method doesn't have an `axis` keyword argument.

```
def cont(Name):
    if 'Charles' in Name:
        return 'Ch'
    return Name
```

You don't even need to define it:

```
titanic['namest'] = titanic['Name'].apply(lambda x: 'Ch' if 'Charles' in x else x)
```